# Why "this" keyword should be used in react click events?

Tags: reactjs

I had a class component and then I created a button and added the onClick event to it. 
Now I created a function to be called when that onClick event fires. 
While referencing the function to onClick, 
Why should we use something like `{this.function-name}` but not simply
 `{function-name}`?

Comment: Because you want the function that's attached to the component?

Comment: because you attach `function-name` to a context which should be your react component which is a javascript `class` without that, how would it know what is `function-name` unless its in the global scope, which is bad.

Comment: Because the methods are defined in the class and to access class properties or methods, you have to use this keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have many functions called `function-name` in different components. When you want to call them, you need to specify exactly which function you are referring to. Using the keyword `this` means you want to use the `function-name` which is attached to your current component.

- `this.function-name`: `function-name` from the current component.
- `otherComponent.function-name`: `function-name` from another component.

Comment: You forgot just plain old `function-name`, which is what the question actually asked :/

Answer (score 1):

It is all about javascript scopes.
For example:

```
class Example extends Component {

    clicked() {
        console.log('clicked');
    }

    render() {

        const innerFuncClicked = () => console.log('inner click');

        return (
            <button
                onClick={clicked}
                onClick={this.clicked}
                onClick={this.clicked.bind(this)}
                onClick={() => this.clicked()}
                onClick={innerFuncClicked}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

As for the above code, I'll describe each "onClick" you will see.
Of course, you cant have several "onclick" as only the last one will override the rest.

1) function "clicked" is not defined in the scope so it will break

2) this will break as well as the "click" is happening inside the button component with a different "this"

3) this will work, as we bind the current "this" to the function

4) It will work as we create an arrow function that doesn't hurt the current "this"

5) this will work as the func "innerFuncClicked" exists in the scope

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read the basic understanding of 'this'.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

console.log(this === window);  //true

Basically, this is keyword which help us to bind your custom function/ event to global 'window' events.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Not only for React, it's common for all JavaScript.